# Django ignoring DEBUG value when I use os.environ, why?

Tags: python, django

In my Django settings I have the following:

> DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE']

Where `DEBUG_VALUE = False`

However, Django continues to show full error messages when I do this. If I manual add `DEBUG = False` it works and shows 500 error.

For some reason Django is ignoring it when I use the `os.environ` value.

I have confirmed `DEBUG_VALUE` is False but outputting to a file.

I have even tried:

> DEBUG = bool(os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'])

and still shows full errors.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The value of `os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE']` is a string and `bool('non empty string') == True`.

You should do something similar to:

```
DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] == 'TRUE'
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I tried what you said ``os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] == 'TRUE'`` now it just evaluates to False even when env is set to True

Comment: @GlynJackson Try with `os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] == 'True'`, it needs to be the value of the environment variable you set.

Comment: ok your second example work, however I'm not sure what it does could you explain, why == 'True' ? Many thanks

Comment: @GlynJackson Python does not parse environment variables to Python objects, it just gets them as strings. If you set the environment variable `DEBUG_VALUE` to `True`, `os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE']` will return the string `'True'`, not the boolean `True`

Comment: @GlynJackson `==` is the equality operator, the result of this operation is either `True` or `False` so `DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] == 'TRUE'` means if `os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] ` equals the string `'True'` then the `DEBUG` variable is set to `True` else it is set to `False`.

Comment: Thanks, that had me stumped like a newbie :)

Comment: @aumo so really it doesn't matter what value you use in production since "False" and "FooBar" would both evaluate to False.

Comment: @pspahn in this simple case no. If needed, validation logic can be added which might be a good idea to prevent typos

Comment: If changing the .env value causes no change, try restaring your shell session.

Answer (score 18):

The `django-environ` package has a simple way of managing this that is more robust and elegant, I think, than having to manually parse the string value (which will always evaluate to true) - you can import your environment as an object.

Export the environment variable and install the package:

```
export MY_DEBUG_ENV_VAR=False
pip install django-environ
```

Then in django, import the environment as an Env() object and use the bool() method to parse a boolean and provide an optional default value:

```
import environ
env = environ.Env()
MY_DEBUG_ENV_VAR = env.bool('MY_DEBUG_ENV_VAR', default=False)
```

Tada! The Env() object also has a bunch of other methods (e.g. for parsing integers, floats, strings etc etc).

NB I found this though the django-cookiecutter application, which has a bunch of equally useful things preinstalled and is a great starting point for projects whether you're new or experienced with django.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want something more forgiving. First allow the local definition for development purposes. And only if not defined, get it from environment variable, but use the case insensitive comparison (since the person doing the deployment might not be the developer writing this line of code).

```
try:
    DEBUG = DEBUG_VALUE_LOCAL
except NameError:
    DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE').lower() == 'true'
```

Comment: ur the best man

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can evaluate with [int(String)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int), if you use 1/0 values, instead of True/False for the environment variable:

```
# Set DEBUG flag. Default is 0 (considered as False in conditions)
DEBUG = int(os.environ.get('DEBUG_VALUE', 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, in my opinion best would be use `strtobool` from `distutils.util`

In python 3 and above

```
#import distutls 
# if you using python version > 3 use from distutils import strtobool
from distutils.util import strtobool 

_DEBUG = bool(strtobool(os.environ['DEBUG_MODE']))
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old post but this has worked for me ALWAYS when I use a .env with a DEBUG variable set to either 0 or 1.

```
DEBUG = (bool(int(os.environ.get('DEBUG',1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the method provided by @aumo (DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG_VALUE'] == 'TRUE') works fine even if you need to pass the parameters on systemd init file
eg:

```
[Unit]
Description=Sample Application using Daphne
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=DEBUG=False
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/

User=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/projects/sampleapp/app
ExecStart=/var/projects/sampleapp/env/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000 app.asgi:application
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and in settings file something like this:

```
DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG') == 'True'
```

Answer (score 0):

Robust logic to this would be:

```
DEBUG = os.environ.get('DEBUG', False) == 'True'
```